How do I adjust screen brightness linearly?
Got a new Samsung Galaxy A55 5G running Android 14, One UI 6.1, and discovered (among other modern horrors) that the brightness bar control is wildly logarithmic.
This means that being on like 10% of the bar puts you at 50% brightness (and in my opinion is already way too bright). It makes it extremely difficult to adjust brightness however I want to.
Before I go and make myself a widget to handle this myself, are there any known ways of managing brightness linearly?
